# GnuPG. File size limit?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

Is there a file size limit for encrypting a single file with GnuPG(1.0.xx,2.0.xx,2.1.xx)?
The file size ranges from about 2GiB to 100GiB. I'm not worried about the 2Gib but I'm not really sure if it's a good idea to encrypt a single 100GiB file. Do I run into problems if I do that or is it perfectly safe to encrypt such large files?
I checked the FAQ on https://gnupg.org/ and only found an article dealing with
file size limits of the different ciphers but not if there is a limitation of the program itself. Here is the link to the specific part:
https://gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html#recommended_ciphers

Kind regards

Comment: Probably you know this but I will make it clear for those who don't: GPG is documented either "symmetric" or "asymmetric" encryption. Actually the "asymmetric" encryption uses symmetric underneath, and only uses asymmetric to send/hide the symmetric encryption key. GPG allows specifying the "cipher" used for the symmetric encryption: "--cipher-algo" <- See the online manual [ gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html ].  There is size limit for some ciphers as explained in YOUR line and grawity's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Do I run into problems if I do that or is it perfectly safe to encrypt such large files?

The file size limit is Operating System dependent.

```
--max-output n
                 This option sets a limit on the number of bytes that will  be
                 generated  when  processing  a  file.  Since OpenPGP supports
                 various levels of compression, it is possible that the plain-
                 text  of a given message may be significantly larger than the
                 original OpenPGP message.  While GnuPG  works  properly  with
                 such  messages, there is often a desire to set a maximum file
                 size that will be generated before processing  is  forced  to
                 stop  by  the  OS  limits.   Defaults  to  0, which means "no
                 limit".
```

Source  [gpg](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/gpg1.html)

Answer (score 2):

There's no limit, only a possible security issue.

- The OpenPGP format according to RFC 4880 has no limits on file size (although a single packet is limited to ~4 GiB, the file will simply be stored as a series of partial packets).
- Some 32-bit versions of various OpenPGP software *might* have a limit of 2 or 4 GiB per file. So if you encrypt a file, it's not guaranteed that old computers will be able to decrypt it.

  Software compiled for 64-bit should have no problems. (I haven't tested 32-bit GnuPG, but I think it should be fine.)
- Make sure to **avoid old ciphers** using 64-bit block sizes (such as IDEA or Blowfish) due to possible security problems similar to the [Sweet32](https://sweet32.info/) attack.

  Ciphers with larger block sizes, such as AES, have no practical limits, but they didn't become the default in GnuPG until very recently (I think 2.1.x) – and even then, if you're encrypting to someone else, their's old pubkey, it might have "preferences" stored that tell the software to use a specific old cipher.

Comment: As `gpg` can encrypt in pipeline there is no "_file size_" in such a situation, but rather length of stream. Are you saying that encrypting large byte-streams / files could produce weaker security due to repetitions (or something)? For example, a 1.4 TiB disk image I have could suffer from weakened security, simply due to it's size.

Answer (score 0):

There may be no official limits but I have had no success encrypting 10Gb files with Gpg4win with an rsa2048 key. Kleopatra crashed after 56MB's and GPA will encrypt and decrypt the file but I can't open it after creating it. What's more it also creates 0byte checksums of such large files.